# PHP while loop if column empty insert last non blank value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

in php how to insert empty column replace with last non blank value in while loop

```
in table data = '1'
     data=''
     data=''
     data='2'
     data=''
wwhile($row= mysqli_fetch_array($query_chapter)){
      echo $row[data]; }
echo  like 

1
1
1
2
2
```

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Anyway to answer your question, on the first loop you simply need to store the value from that row in a separate variable (which has scope outside the loop). Then each time you loop, check if the row value is empty. If it's empty, replace it with the value you stored from the earlier row. If it's not empty, replace the stored value with the new one. The logic is fairly simple, so I think you can try it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$lastNonEmptyData = '';
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($query_chapter)) {
    if ($row['data'] !== '') {
        $lastNonEmptyData = $row['data'];
    }
    echo $lastNonEmptyData; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $single_variable = ''; 
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($query_chapter)){

      if (!empty($row[data])){
                 unset($single_variable);
                 echo $single_variable .= $row[data];
                }else{
             echo $single_variable .= $row[data]; 
             }  
       }
```